# Consumer not receiving message in Apache Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, messagebroker

I am building an Apache Kafka consumer to subscribe to another already running Kafka. Now, my problem is that when my producer pushes message to a server...my consumer does not receive them. 
**Here I give Producer code,**

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("metadata.broker.list","Running kafka ip addr:9092");
        properties.put("serializer.class","kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        ProducerConfig producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(properties);
        kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<String,String> producer = new kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<String, String>(producerConfig);
        String filePath="filepath";
        File rootFile= new File(filePath);
        Collection<File> allFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(rootFile, CanReadFileFilter.CAN_READ, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
        for(File file : allFiles) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(file);
            KeyedMessage<String, String> message =new KeyedMessage<String, String>(TOPIC,sb.toString());
            System.out.println("sending msg from producer.."+sb.toString());
            producer.send(message);
        }
           producer.close();
```

**Here Consumer code,**

```
         properties.put("bootstrap.servers","Running zookeaper ip addr:2181");
         properties.put("group.id","test-group");
         properties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
         properties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
         properties.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");

         KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
         consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topicName)); 
         while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
                {
                    System.out.println("topic = "+record.topic());
                    System.out.println("topic = "+record.partition());
                    System.out.println("topic = "+record.offset());
                }
                try {
                  consumer.commitSync(); 
                } catch (CommitFailedException e) {
                    System.out.printf("commit failed", e) ;
                }
            }
```

I use this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**I get all information from that link:**
https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

When we running consumer, we didn't get any notification from the consumer side. Please give me any idea.

Comment: try to figure out where is the problem: on consumer or producer size. For this: check offsets in topic. It can be done from command line

Comment: You are running it as a jar file on cluster?..please verify your zookeeper port.

Comment: @Natalia: I am able to post the messages through producer. I can see the message number increasing along with the log size..but offset is not increasing...

Comment: @KetanKeshri - I am running in eclipse as of now..

Comment: You  check that your kafka is working correctly by using the command line tools.For that you need to produce messages with the command line producer `kafka-console-producer` and then make sure that the messages get consumed with the command line consumer `kafka-console-consumer`
https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_send

Comment: @saloua- Yes both Kafka producer and consumer running perfectly but  still not getting any message in consumer side

Comment: @Jitendra kumar- Please try once by running it locally on the cluster where kafka+zookeeper is installed by making a jar of your code.

Comment: @Jitendrakumar Do you mean that you are not getting any message from the command line consumer `kafka-console-consumer` ?

Comment: If the command line consumer is not getting any produced message then you certainly have an error in the configuration of your brokers.

Answer (score 0):

For producer:

> ```
>    properties.put("metadata.broker.list","Running kafka ip addr:9092");
> ```

I guess, this should be "bootstrap.servers".

For consumer:

> ```
> properties.put("bootstrap.servers","Running zookeaper ip addr:2181");
> ```

`bootstrap.servers` must point to a broker, not to ZK.

The "problem" is, that the consumer will just wait for a broker but not fail if there is no broker at the specified host/port.

Comment: We are running both broker and zookeeper in the same ip. Its a single node installation. Hence gave the same ip.Do I have to run zookeeper and broker in different vms??

Comment: You don't need to run on different servers -- but it's recommended. Anyway, ZK and broker use different ports, and `2181` is ZK default port -- so I guess you need up point to broker port (default: `9092`)

Comment: @ Matthias J. Sax - did  in same but still not getting  any message in consumer side

Comment: Just updated my answer. Is your producer setting correct? You should check the broker /client logs if producer/consumer do connect successfully to the broker, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newb at Kafka and Java, but i'll like to suggest the following approach

- Verify that the producer is actually writing to the topic using the following command `/usr/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --new-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic KumarTopic --from-beginning`.
- If it is, you'll probably need to focus on your consumer code. Confluent's guides are pretty helpful.

Comment: @Zigmaphi-Thnaks for comment, I already checked. Producer writing in topic perfectly and consumer also running but still not getting any message